# Check Like Form Fields for Value

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if there is a way to use JavaScript to check all form fields with a similar name for a specific value.

I have several hidden fields on my form with names like "associd1", "associd2" etc..

Is there a way to loop through all fields with a name like "associd" and check the value of those fields for a certain value?

Comment: Yes there is. What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is. Get them with `document.querySelectorAll` or jQuery and set their `checked` property. Give it a try and come back with your code if you have questions or problems.